# SparkJava Web browser downloads html file instead of showing when deploying war file

Tags: java, spark-java

When I run my web app through Intellij it works ok. Going to `localhost:4567` and apache opens index.html page. But when I deploy war file and run it with `java -jar project.war` it downloads the index.html page

I have folder `public` in my resources. index.html lays there

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder();
        Integer port;
        if (process.environment().get("PORT") != null) {
            port = Integer.parseInt(process.environment().get("PORT"));
        } else {
            port = 4567;
        }

        port(port);
        staticFileLocation("/public");
}
```

What am I missing? if you need any additional info please let me know in the comments

Comment: @mazaneicha sparkjava is a web framework, not a big data library

Comment: you should really change "Apache Spark" in your title then. There is only one Apache Spark https://spark.apache.org/ and it is a distributed computing framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should use version 2.7.2 or higher, previous versions are bugged